# OpenGeoDB: migrate mySQL data to postgreSQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgis

I would like to use [OpenGeoDB](http://opengeodb.giswiki.org/wiki/OpenGeoDB) for my Ruby on Rails project. Kostiantyn Kahanskyi has written the [active_geo_db](https://github.com/kostia/active_geo_db) gem which is a "Rails (ActiveRecord) lib for accessing OpenGeoDb". The problem is that it uses MySQL and I use PostgreSQL. Is there a way to use PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

The OpenGeoDB documentation makes it look like it [works with PostgreSQL/PostGIS](http://opengeodb.org/wiki/OpengeoDB_mit_PostGIS). Ruby on Rails / ActiveRecord [works with PostGIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298797/rails-with-postgis). active_geo_db itself isn't very big so once you have ActiveRecord w/ PostGIS and OpenGeoDB working properly, it should be relatively simple to refactor active_geo_db to work with your setup. If you run in to problems refactoring, perhaps you can post a more concrete follow-up question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want to migrate MySQL data to PostgreSQL.  In my experience it is usually easiest to manually migrate the schemas.   This is because existing tools have lots of blind spots.  It's often easier to just go through the files, use sed to convert the quotes, and then rewrite it line by line.

Converting the data is often more difficult.  The key issue is that different systems may have different representations.  Your best bet here is to write a tool that reads from the MySQL db, converts the data as needed, and writes it to a PostgreSQL db.  To the extent you can use gems that can handle the representations through a similar abstraction layer, you can avoid having to deal with these issues yourself.